# No se pudo encontrar cadena de conexion Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Me salta un error usando entity framework y no lo puedo descubrir.
El proyecto que estoy haciendo esta dividido en 3 capas MVC, lo cual en la capa de datos tengo el modelo de la base de datos y la conexion y en la de negocio todos los metodos; pero cuando quiero traer todos los dueños me salta este error.

Dicho sea de paso me fije en el `app.config`, en la clase y el nombre esta todo bien. ¿Que podria ser?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.config:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica en contenido de tu app.config para poder ayudarte

Comment: Y el contenido de tu clase DBContext si estas usando Code First.

Comment: Este app config es el que esta en tu proyecto? o es que tienes copiado en la carpeta bin/debug en donde el programa se ejecuta ?, tal vez tienes mal configurado el app.config y no se esta actualizando en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Si la solucion esta compuesta por varios proyectos seguramente tengas algunos del tipo 'Class Library' uno que defines como inicio, seguramente sea Windows Application o Web Site.

Lo que tienes que hacer es mover la seccion de configuracion de entity framework del app.config que esta dentro del proyecto Class Library (el que compila a dll) al app.config del proyecto que defines como inicio.

Recuerda que de forma automatica la configuracion se toma del config del proyecto que ejecuta. Si la configuracion esta en un .config dentro de una dll no lo leera.